# Button to change color when active with JQuery

Tags: jquery

When I press the button nothing happens, color is the same.

HTML:

```
<div class="fadebox leadstyle-container">
   <p class="button" data-lead-id="button-id">
      <a href="http://..." class="btn leadstyle-link" target="_blank" style="display: block;">Register for a Live Online Event w/ Mark Allen &amp; Dave Scott</a>
   </p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn leadstyle-link").click(function(){
   $(this).css("background-color","#0f6832");

   });
});
```

I tried selecting all classes in the div and children with JQuery to no avail.
I can provide CSS too, if needed.

Comment: Your selector is wrong.  It should be `.btn.leadstyle-link`.

Comment: Nice observation, however color is still the same.

Comment: Are you sure it's the link background colour you want to change, and not the `p.button` element?

Comment: I tried selecting all. Same thing.

Comment: Can you give a link to show one of these buttons in action?

Answer (score 0):

Your selector isnt right. The element has two classes `btn` and `leadstyle-link`. So do something like this :

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
....
}
```

or

```
 $(".leadstyle-link").click(function(){
    ....
 }
```

or as Archer has mentioned, use an intersection - for **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/mo9vtuf0/)**.

Comment: Or use both, as I suggested and he says doesn't work.

Comment: @Archer, sounds peculiar.

Comment: He is actually right. It doesn't produce the desired effect.

Comment: @nosille - I have updated my answer. Have a look and see what you're doing differently. Perhaps your CSS might be conflicting with this change.

Comment: It's perfectly normal and common practice.  Say you have a bunch of buttons that share common styles - you give them a class of `.btn`.  You can then add individual styles to each button with extra classes, like `.leadstyle-link`.  If you take that one step further then you can apply that 2nd style to other elements that do not share the first style (common fonts, colours etc. for associated elements), then you can use `.btn.leadstyle-link` to reference just the buttons with the 2nd style, and nothing else.  It obviously depends how you work, but it's very useful to know.

Comment: @Archer Yes I happen to have used intersections before, I said "peculiar" because the OP claims he didnt get the desired effect when he used intersection. Also, In the example I have provided I have only used intersection :)

Comment: Sorry - my misunderstanding :)

Answer (score -1):

You can't select multiple classes in jQuery. I corrected your code:

```
$(".fadebox").on('click', function(){
       $(".fadebox").backgroundColor='#0f6832';
});
```

1) I not used the "this" because I'm not very expert with the OOP.
2) I used "backgroundColor" (JavaScript).
3) The event (on document ready) is useless because is stupid put an event in other event.
4) You can't change the backgroundColor of "A" element, I think your button is created with the "div" (class Fadebox).

Try the code to see if this function or not.

Comment: This is completely wrong.  Firstly, the selector in the event handler will select *all* elements with the `fadebox` class, and secondly jQuery objects do not have a `backgroundColor` property.

Comment: Thank you Archer, I'm not very expert :D